# Saber o número de linha de um arquivo txt em c

Tags: c

Existem alguma função ou forma de descobrir quantas linhas tem um arquivo, sem precisar abri-lo? Preciso dividir um arquivo em duas partes, para que dois processos leiam ele ao "mesmo tempo". Irei usar a função fseek() para mover o ponteiro para certa posição do arquivo, mas preciso descobrir quantas linhas tem o arquivo para ser feita a divisão.

Comment: Não existe uma forma universal de descobrir quantos linhas um arquivo tem sem abri-lo. No Unix e suas derivações, você pode utilizar o comando stat ou o fstat em C para descobrir qual o tamanho em bytes do arquivo. Com isso, você pode abrir o arquivo em dois processos, dividindo pelo tamanho em bytes do arquivo. Mesmo assim, a forma recomendada para descobrir quantas linhas ou quantos bytes um arquivo tem é abrindo-o e contando os bytes ou os caracteres de nova linha. Você pode usar a função fseek para isso.

Comment: As linhas do teu arquivo têm todas o mesmo comprimento? Se souberes quantos bytes o arquivo ocupa ([stat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html)) e dividires pela tamanho da linha obtens o numero de linhas sem abrir o ficheiro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem abrir o arquivo acredito que não tem como obter essa informação.

Mas se você usa UNIX você pode usar o comando `wc` pra descobrir o numero de linhas.

`wc nomedoarquivo`

---

Caso você resolva abrir o arquivo, uma forma que sempre uso pra percorrer o arquivo rapidamente e contar o número de linhas é com esse código:

```
while (EOF != (scanf("%*[^\n]") && scanf("%*c"))) 
    ++numLinha;
```