# Contar as linhas de um arquivo txt em c / c++

Tags: c, arquivo, terminologia

Na aula de arquivos o professor usava " `EOF` " para determinar se o arquivo tinha chegado ao seu fim, porém lendo a página da [wiki](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_em_arquivos) sobre arquivos em c, eu vi que a implementação da checagem do fim de um arquivo é " `FEOF` ", as duas terminologias funcionam ?

Tentei implementar o algoritmo paracido com esse [aqui](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_em_arquivos) ou [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16504/saber-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-linha-de-um-arquivo-txt-em-c) para realizar a contagem de linhas de um arquivo txt, porém gerou vários erros na questão do uso do " FEOf " ( e sua comparação com o arquivo lido ) e acabou que fiz essa gambiarra:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main () {

    FILE *arq;

    char text[200], letra = '\n';

    int vezes;

    arq = fopen("teste.txt","r");

        fread (&text, sizeof(char), 200, arq);

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++){

            if(text[i] == letra){

                vezes++;

            }
        }

    printf("\nLinhas: %i\n",vezes + 1);

    fclose(arq);

}
```

Poderiam dar um explicação sucinta a respeito da implementação dos já citados link's acima, ou me **explicar** se e como fazer a gambiarra acima deixar de ser uma " gambiara " sem que eu tenha de acrescentar " +1 " para gerar o resultado certo e sem que o vetor seja estático, ou seja fazer o tal item com ponteiro sendo do tamanho exato do conteúdo arquivo ?

Comment: Pergunta Relacionada com EOF vs FEOF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164718/confusion-with-eof-vs-feof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um jeito mais fácil é usar o próprio retorno da função fread, quando retornar 0 significa que terminou o arquivo (e em C é como se fosse o false). Então seu código fica +- assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main () {

    FILE *arq;

    char c, letra = '\n';

    int vezes;

    arq = fopen("teste.txt","r");

        //Lendo o arquivo 1 por 1
        while(fread (&c, sizeof(char), 1, arq)) {
            if(c == letra) {
                vezes++;
            }
        } 

    printf("\nLinhas: %i\n",vezes + 1);

    fclose(arq);

}
```

Sei que não é exatamente essa a sua dúvida, mas é um jeito de resolver seu problema sem se preocupar com o EOF.

Comment: Cara, muito bom!! muito obrigado!!!