# Como contar elementos de um Arquivo em C?

Tags: c, arquivo

Eu tenho o seguinte problema para resolver da faculdade, porém até o momento não enxerguei uma solução válida... Fiz o seguinte código até o momento do envio desde pedido de ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
//
//  2.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 10/17/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){


    FILE *p;
    char texto[20];
    char pular = '\n';
    int i = 0, count = 0, rpt = 1;

    p = fopen("Text.txt", "w");
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Erro na leitura");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(rpt != 0){
        printf("Digite uma linha: ");
        scanf("%s",      texto);
        fprintf(p, "%s", texto);

        printf("Deseja repetir? ");
        scanf("%d", &rpt);
    }
    fclose(p);

    p = fopen("Text.txt",  "w");
    fread(&texto, sizeof(char), 20, p);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++) {
        if (fscanf(p, "%s\n", &texto[i]) == pular) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(p);

    printf("Total de linhas: %d\n", count);
    return 0;

}
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como resolver o problema acima?

Comment: Não tem sentido você usar fread e fscanf misturados no mesmo arquivo. Certamente fread não é a melhor opção para a leitura de um arquivo texto. Outra consideração: se for detectado o fim do arquivo e o caractere lido imediatamente antes não for um '\n' você não deveria somar 1 à quantidade de linhas?

Answer (score 1):

Leire,

Abaixo um exemplo comentado de como efetuar essa leitura, sendo que o nome do arquivo será solicitado ao usuário:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //Nome do arquivo
  char nomeDoArquivo[50];

  printf("Qual o nome do arquivo: ");

  //Solicita o usuário o nome do arquivo que será avaliado a quantidade de linhas
  scanf("%s", nomeDoArquivo);

  //Abre o arquivo como leitura
  FILE *fp = fopen(nomeDoArquivo,"r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    //Sai do programa caso o arquivo não tenha sido aberto
    printf("Erro ano tentar abrir o arquivo.");
    return 1;
  } else {
    int ch = 0;
    int linhas = 0;

    linhas++;

    //Efetua a contagem de linhas lendo o arquivo e procurando a quebra de linha
    while (!feof(fp)) {
      ch = fgetc(fp);

      if (ch == '\n') {
        linhas++;
      }
    }

    //Fecha o arquivo
    fclose(fp);

    //Exibe a quantidade de linhas
    printf("Quantidade de linhas: %d\n",linhas);

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Aqui você consegue executar esse código:
https://repl.it/repls/VividEarnestShelfware

---

Esse é apenas um exemplo, sempre existem formas distintas de chegar ao mesmo resultado, veja aqui um outro exemplo:
[Contar as linhas de um arquivo txt em c / c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167966/contar-as-linhas-de-um-arquivo-txt-em-c-c)

Comment: Daniel! Obrigado, estou começando a ver arquivos agora. Na verdade já foi passado as explicações mas acabei faltando e estou tentando me recuperar. Não tinha conhecimento ainda sobre feof, fgetc dentre outros. Tenho mais algumas atividades similares a essa vou botar em prática! Obrigado.